# Cannot register interrupt for a PCI shared interrupt line

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

Good night,

I am trying to code some simple linux module that registers an existent shared IRQ line.

By looking at `/proc/interrupts`, I can see that the line I want to use has the `irq_no`=17.

For reference here is the output. As we can see the `b43` driver module has already registered on the line, but the flags in the linux kernel code indicate that it is a shared line.

```
           CPU0       CPU1 
  0:     334476     345390   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:         28         26   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  8:          0          1   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          1   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:       1623        153   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 14:          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
 15:          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      ata_piix
 16:        152        129   IO-APIC-fasteoi   nouveau
 17:      46543      40167   IO-APIC-fasteoi   b43
 18:       6129       5015   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ata_piix
 19:         48         28   IO-APIC-fasteoi   firewire_ohci, yenta
 20:          1          1   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2, uhci_hcd:usb3, uhci_hcd:usb5
 21:          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb4, uhci_hcd:usb6
 22:         47         34   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb7
 44:        129        138   PCI-MSI-edge      hda_intel
 45:          2          1   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
NMI:          0          0   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:     227794     229233   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:          0          0   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
RES:     244428     258417   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:        340        462   Function call interrupts
TLB:       1056        916   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:         15         15   Machine check polls
ERR:          0
MIS:          0
```

I am trying to do the following:

```
static int __init ptdk_init(void)
{
     printk(KERN_INFO  "starting the kernel listener to the firmware module.\n"); 
     ptdk_could_not_register = request_threaded_irq(17, (irq_handler_t) ptdk_irq_handler,
                (irq_handler_t) ptdk_threaded_irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED, "ptdk", dummy);
     if (ptdk_could_not_register != 0) {
         printk(KERN_INFO "Could not request an irq for 17. %d", ptdk_could_not_register);
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

The `dummy` is a simple `dev_id` in order to register a cookie so the shared interrupt can free the line with context. (It is required a unique id to request a shared IRQ).

It just follows the following structure:

```
typedef struct{
    int i;
} ptdk_dummy_device;
```

So this should in principle work. But when trying to register the IRQ it returns `-22` which is `-EINVAL`.

Am I missing something important? No other guide seems to give me any solutions.
Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: You have access to the entire kernel code. [Here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/irq/manage.c#L2138) are all the reasons it might return -EINVAL.

Comment: Are you sure `dummy` isn't 0?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `&dummy`? `dev_id` is supposed to be a `void*`

Comment: @user253751, @EmanuelP this doesn't matter. The error happens before `dummy` is even considered.

Comment: why do you think it happens before `dummy` is even considered? The code for the `request_threaded_irq` function clearly shows that it returns -EINVAL if dummy is 0 and IRQF_SHARED is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this as I was trying to make the cookie ID not a valid pointer.

Working code:

```
     ptdk_could_not_register = request_threaded_irq(17, (irq_handler_t) ptdk_irq_handler,
            (irq_handler_t) ptdk_threaded_irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED, "ptdk", &dummy);
```

Please, see the now &dummy.